# "nodemon" is not recognized while running it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodemon

```
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.**
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon tut69.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Please suggest me a proper solution for this.

Comment: seems you have not globally `-g` installed nodemon, if nodemon is in your devDependencys etc then you need to put your start command in a [*scripts*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts), though is a shot in the dark as you have not provided any details other than an standard *its not installed* error message

Comment: Install nodemon  [from this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not globally installed nodemon.

Some solutions for you:

1. Install nodemon globally. Use `npm install -g nodemon`.

   Then try running it again: `nodemon tut69.js`
2. Add script that will start nodemon in package.json.

   ```json
   "scripts": {
      "dev": "nodemon tut69.js"
   },
   ```

   Then run it: `npm run dev`